# Session already started in FOS User Bundle Registration Confirmation

Tags: php, session, symfony, fosuserbundle

I am using FOSUserBundle for user registration. And when confirming a user with /register/confirm/xxxx-token-xxxxx I sometimes get the error "Failed to start the session: already started by PHP ($_SESSION is set)."

This happens in the NativeSessionStorage::start() method. Obviously there is already a session ($_SESSION is an empty array in that case).

This behaviour is very hard to reproduce. It works most of time. I am seeing this in dev and prod environment (both php 5.3.x)

Any idea why $_SESSION is an empty array when initializing the session?

Comment: Somewhere along the line the session is suppose to close and it isn't? You could always add a check: `if( !isset( $_SESSION ) ) { session_start(); }`.

Comment: Which version of Symfony?

Comment: And which version of php? The detailed version number! And do a `grep -nP session_start src/`

Comment: PHP Version (dev Environment) 5.3.23-1~dotdeb.0
PHP Version (prod Environment) 5.3.3-7+squeeze14

Comment: symfony/assetic-bundle               v2.3.0             Integrates Assetic into Symfony2  

symfony/icu                          v1.2.0             Contains an excerpt of the ICU data and classes to load it.  

symfony/monolog-bundle               v2.3.0             Symfony MonologBundle  

symfony/swiftmailer-bundle           v2.3.4             Symfony SwiftmailerBundle  

symfony/symfony                      v2.3.4             The Symfony PHP framework

Comment: friendsofsymfony/user-bundle = v1.3.2

Comment: session_start is only called in DefaultCsrfProvider::getSessionId() and NativeSessionStorage::regenerate()

Answer (score 0):

I solved invalidating the session before redirection.

In the RegistrationController (that I have copied in my bundle and modified), method confirmAction, I changed:

```
   if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
        $url = $this->container->get('router')->generate('fos_user_registration_confirmed');
        $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
    }
```

to:

```
   if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
        $session = $request->getSession();
        $session->invalidate();
        $url = $this->container->get('router')->generate('fos_user_registration_confirmed');
        $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
    }
```

that did the job for me.

Symfony recommends not to use standard PHP session methods such as session_start() and session_destroy().